# При использовании одного слайдера 2-жды пропадают стрелки переключения, что делать?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, css3, вёрстка

Есть слайдер с ним все ок, он указан в примере, при использовании 2-го такого же слайдера, (со другими значениями классов и id) стрелки пропадают с первого, и остаются на 2-м  в чем причина ? Или что нужно прописать стрелкам что бы они были и у первого и у второго ? Или нельзя использовать один слайдер несколько раз на сайте и нужно будет брать другие слайдеры ?

```css
#slider {
  /*положение слайдера*/
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10px;
}

#slider {
  /*центровка слайдера*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slides article {
  /*все изображения справа друг от доруга*/
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#slides .image {
  /*устанавливает общий размер блока с изображениями*/
  width: 500%;
  line-height: 0;
}

#overflow {
  /*сркывает все, что находится за пределами этого блока*/
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article img {
  /*размер изображений слайдера*/
  width: 100%;
}

#desktop:checked~#slider {
  /*размер всего слайдера*/
  max-width: 960px;
  /*максимальнная длинна*/
}


/*настройка переключения и положения для левой стрелки*/


/*если свич1-5 активны, то идет обращение к лейблу из блока с id контролс*/

#switch1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(5),
#switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1),
#switch3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch4:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4) {
  background: url('prev.png') no-repeat;
  /*заливка фона картинкой без повторений*/
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 -84px;
  /*сдвиг влево*/
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
}


/*настройка переключения и положения для правой стрелки*/

#switch1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4),
#switch4:checked~#controls label:nth-child(5),
#switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1) {
  background: url('next.png') no-repeat;
  /*заливка фона картинкой без повторений*/
  float: right;
  margin: 0 -84px 0 0;
  /*сдвиг вправо*/
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
}

label,
a {
  /*при наведении на стрелки или переключатели - курсор изменится*/
  cursor: pointer;
}

.all input {
  /*скрывает стандартные инпуты (чекбоксы) на странице*/
  display: none;
}


/*позиция изображения при активации переключателя*/

#switch1:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#switch2:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#switch3:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#switch4:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

#switch5:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -400%;
}

#controls {
  /*положение блока всех управляющих элементов*/
  margin: -25% 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

#active label {
  /*стиль отдельного переключателя*/
  border-radius: 10px;
  /*скругление углов*/
  display: inline-block;
  /*расположение в строку*/
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #bbb;
}

#active {
  /*расположение блока с переключателями*/
  margin: 23% 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#active label:hover {
  /*поведение чекбокса при наведении*/
  background: #76c8ff;
  border-color: #777 !important;
  /*выполнение в любом случае*/
}


/*цвет активного лейбла при активации чекбокса*/

#switch1:checked~#active label:nth-child(1),
#switch2:checked~#active label:nth-child(2),
#switch3:checked~#active label:nth-child(3),
#switch4:checked~#active label:nth-child(4),
#switch5:checked~#active label:nth-child(5) {
  background: #18a3dd;
  border-color: #18a3dd !important;
}

#slides .image {
  /*анимация пролистывания изображений*/
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
}

#controls label:hover {
  /*прозрачность стрелок при наведении*/
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#controls label {
  /*прозрачность стрелок при отводе курсора*/
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <input checked type="radio" name="respond" id="desktop">
  <article id="slider">
    <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="switch1">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch2">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch3">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch4">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch5">
    <div id="slides">
      <div id="overflow">
        <div class="image">
          <article><img src="http://333v.ru/uploads/00/000a7db0d4c688263a3e8d09e1f5fa93.jpg"></article>
          <article><img src="https://million-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/6/84/484414688157351.jpg"></article>
          <article><img src="http://bestwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Angry-Cheetah.jpg"></article>
          <article><img src="http://img11.nnm.me/f/7/c/9/6/6a4ae327a93ca29b06ff90615ed.jpg"></article>
          <article><img src="http://wallpul.info/i/2016/12/wallpapers-nature-wallpaper-4k-nature-mountain-forest-landscape-fog-lake-ultrahd-4k-wallpaper-wide-hd.jpg"></article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
      <label for="switch1"></label>
      <label for="switch2"></label>
      <label for="switch3"></label>
      <label for="switch4"></label>
      <label for="switch5"></label>
    </div>
    <div id="active">
      <label for="switch1"></label>
      <label for="switch2"></label>
      <label for="switch3"></label>
      <label for="switch4"></label>
      <label for="switch5"></label>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте код вызова слайдера и какой слайдер вы используете?

Comment: Вы меняете `id`, `name` у `<input />` у второго слайдера? Если нет, то все `label`  будет управлять только первым (или наоборот вторым, не помню) слайдером.